# Ads with a JavaFX applet based website

Tags: google-analytics, javafx

What is the best way to make a website based on JavaFX supported with ad revenue?  Do you have to put the ads out side of the applet in the regular html space, or can you use JWebPane to render the add inside the applet?

Answer (score 2):

My opinion is that you'll have a hard time convincing marketing and ad agencies to invest in JavaFX based designs. They would have to be very compelling.  Flash is the category killer for interactive designs.  These decisions cost companies a lot of dollars.  I've seen developers screw up the onclick mechanism on banner ads and likely screw their advertisers out of a lot of responses due to pop-up blockers.  Companies are not inclined to move away from a tried-and-true approach. That is why Silverlight is having such a tough time getting saturation.  Their ace-in-the-hole was gonna be HD support for media.  Even with that leap forward, they are having a hard time attaining penetration. From what I understand, the number of people installing Java in their browsers is on the decline (still a respectable number at 80%).  Sun was hoping their niche was going to be ubiquity (available on on devices).  But battery drain is a concern of Apple, who won't sanction java on the iPhone.

Officially Sun plans to support what you envision.  They call it Project Insight.

In the meantime, ff you want to use Google Analytics, you can still just add the script outside the applet.  Just don't expect good search discovery unless you also plan for that (maybe using metadata).

In terms of deep-linking which is necessary for click-through tracking, I think you're out of luck.  If you want to use JavaFX to create dynamic content, don't expect it to be searchable or trackable.

Have a look at Project Insight.  Maybe you can beat them to the punch (they seem to be taking their sweet time, as JWebPane was promised last year).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track users actions such as button presses inside your JavaFX web application with Google Analytics then you can try using gaforjavafx ( Google Analytics for JavaFX). Gaforjavafx is a software module for integrating the Google Analytics Tracker API with your JavaFX web application. The following blog explains how to use gaforjavafx in your JavaFX program to send tracking information to Google Analytics.

http://gaforjavafx.blogspot.com/

.